# Mercurial, revert files to a past revision by wildcard?

Tags: mercurial

```
hg revert -r 4 -I *.aspx
```

isn't working for me. Any help? And no, I don't want to use TortoiseHG.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `hg revert -r 4 -I **/*.aspx` *from the root directory of the repository*.  The `**.aspx` matches any file in any subdirectory in the repository whereas `*.aspx` only matches them in the current directory.

See `hg help patterns` for more information, which I've just noticed shows a regexp-based alternative:

```
  hg revert re:.*\.aspx$
```

Comment: @niall hg revert -r 4 re:.*\.aspx$ did it thanks. I'll be marking this as the answer. All the best! Question, why did the other not work

Comment: @jonathan: did some experimentation and you need to run the command from the repo's root.

Comment: @niall I ran all of the commands from the root. I am using an older version of hg though. version 1.5.1. Could that be the problem?