# using hg revert to revert a group of files in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, revert

I'm using Mercurial to read and debug a complex project, and my modify of the project can be divided into different group of files clearly. For example, if I modified four files

```
src1.cc src1.hh src2.cc src2.hh
```

It's apparent that I can divide them into two file groups such as group *src1* includes `src1.cc src1.hh` and group src2 includes `src2.cc src2.hh`.

I'm wondering if I can revert a group of files by a simple command like 'hg revert group-name-alias' instead of listing all the filename of the group, which is a awful idea if I have modified many files?

Any help really appreciated!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906629/mercurial-revert-only-my-aspx-files-to-a-past-revision

Answer (score 5):

From what I can understand of your use-case, you can:

1. Use patterns in the `hg revert` command. This means that you can
   run `hg revert src1*` to revert all the first group.

   Most probably, though, your stuff is in sub-folders and thankfully 
   you can specify a parent folder to the `revert` command.

   So say your files are really like: `foo/src1.cc`, `foo/src1.hh`,
   `bar/src2.cc`, `bar/src2.hh`. In that case, you can revert all the
   second group with `hg revert bar`, assuming you're in the top folder.
   If you're already in the `bar` folder, you can run `hg revert .`.

   You can specify several patterns.
2. Use [Mercurial queues](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/managing-change-with-mercurial-queues.html) if each one of your "file groups" is also
   a different unit of work (a different bug fix or feature). This is not
   so desirable if all files belong to the same unit of work, though.

Answer (score 4):

No. To the best of my knowledge, Mercurial has no mechanism for grouping files.

You could do some trickery with aliases (`[alias] revert-group-name = revert src2.cc src2.hh` in `~/.hgrc`), but aliases can only be prefixes, and can't perform variable expansions.

If your files are simple enough, you could use shell globbing (`hg revert src2*`), or a shell variable (`GROUP_NAME="src2.cc src2.hh"`, then `hg revert $GROUP_NAME`).

You could also consider writing a small Mercurial extension. If you know Python, they don't take very long (my first took me about 30 minutes).

Answer (score 3):

If the filenames meet patterns, you can use that pattern:

```
hg revert src1*
```

or

```
hg revert src1*.*
```

If those files are in a specific directory, you can do this:

```
hg revert dir\*
```

If the directory is more than one level deep and you want to get that directory and all its subdirectories, you can use this version of that commend:

```
hg revert dir\**\*
```